# ODBC 32 bit Access driver fails on unicode paths?

Tags: winapi, unicode, odbc

Sometimes I swear we're living in the digital stone ages.

It turns out - unless someone can point me to something I'm missing, that ODBC 32 bit cannot handle a unicode pathname which contains non-default-locale characters in it.

It *does* handle a pathname that has non-English chars if the local system is set to be in that same default locale (e.g. Kanji chars when the locale is Japan).

But it **fails** utterly with "Not a valid filename" from both our code, and from the ODBC 32 bit control panel, for a pathname which contains non-default-locale characters in it.

That same file does load properly using the 64 bit ODBC control panel, and it loads just fine running MS Access 2013 on the pathname directly.

> "C:\Users\steve\Desktop\タシロ\Cimex2.mdb"

From the ODBC 32 control panel, this results in:

> ODBC Microsoft Access Driver Login Failed
>   Not a valid file name.

Or from our code calling into ODBC directly as a 32-bit process I get:

> Not a valid file name.
>   Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed

Which is due to an error retcode in a call to:

```
::SQLDriverConnect(hDBC, hWnd, pszConnectInput, SQL_NTS, szConnectOutput, 
                   _countof(szConnectOutput), &nResult, wConnectOption));
```

***UPDATE***: I was asked to provide the runtime state at the point of this call:

*The connection was created using:*

```
L"DSN=Cimex Database|UserCommitSync=Yes|DBQ=C:\\Users\\steve\\Desktop\\タシロ\\Cimex2.mdb"
```

*And the`SQLDriverConnect` is being passed:*

```
L"DSN=Cimex Database;"
```

*And I have verified that the ODBC connection that is created is indeed valid (other than it also fails due to invalid filename from the ODBC cpl) - but if I change the pathname to use a non Kanji path, then this all works as it has for ages).  Similarly, I have manually created an ODBC connection directly and from scratch in the ODBC 32 cpl - as well as in the ODBC 64 cp - and for identical settings - only the 64 bit version works - same .mdb & path - but the 32 bit fails.  And lest you think "it must be the .mdb" - if I put the .mdb in a non-Kanji path, it works just fine from our software and from the ODBC 32 cpl.*

So, it appears to me, and I cannot find a loop-hole, that 32bit ODBC Access driver simply cannot handle Unicode path names that have non-default-locale characters in them. >:(

*Note: I thought maybe SQL_NTS should be SQL_NTSL (I cannot for the life of me find a !@#$!@#$ definition of those two different arguments), but rewiring the calls to end up with SQL_NTSL doesn't help - same results*

**Anyone want to confirm or deny that this is a major freakin' bug still lurking in MS's 32bit Access ODBC implementation (and since it's all Jet engine based - then presumably this applies to all DBs which go through the 32 bit Jet engine)?**

Comment: Can you show how pszConnectInput is defined and what value it has at the time of the SQLDriverConnect call?

Comment: Updated to include the info you requested and more exposition on what I've tried to date

Comment: no, that's not the issue.  you can trivially confirm that by looking at the string that the debugger hands back - which is an L"" string, and correctly contains the UTF-16LE characters desired, as I've shown above.

Comment: That's strange. It works with Unicode but not if the filename includes non-ASCII characters like `L"タシロ"` (ps, it needs `(SQLWCHAR*)` cast but that doesn't solve the problem)

Comment: Sounds, like there is some ANSI code lingering in the ODBC driver. The fact, that you can use Unicode pathnames, as long as all code points can be represented in the calling thread's ANSI codepage, but not otherwise, strongly suggests that. Have you tried passing the short pathname ([GetShortPathName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364989.aspx)) instead?

Comment: @IInspectable That's my conclusion as well.  Someone is dropping down to current locale in some part of their 32 bit driver, but not their 64 bit driver.  Maybe they rewrote it, or just caught that bug when they revamped for 64 bit code?
I don't think short paths will help - most Win filesystems have SFNs disabled by default.